# How to retrieve a value from a deeply nested Hashtable with arbitrary depth?

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, recursion, data-structures

I am having trouble retrieving a value once it has been found. I started out creating a Hashtable of values, but eventually found out that I would need to have a nested Hashtable. As the problem developed I found out that i would need multiple layers of unknown depth. Essentially creating a tree of Hashtables. I'm not really sure if this was a good approach, but its the one I came to as the problem became increasingly complex.

I have a way to dynamically create the branching structure, but the issue comes when I want to retrieve a particular branch given string key to search for. Since the depth of the structure is unknown I figured the only way to traverse through would be to recursively dive into each branch and check if the string value exists on that level's keyset.

The issue I am having with this particular section is once the value is found i return that branch, but as it winds down through the stack the desired value ends up getting clobbered. I feel like I am really close, but might just be missing something. I considered just throwing an exception once the value is found and catching the desired value as an exception. However, I feel like there should be a more correct was to do this. Any help or advice on how to correctly implement my recursive function or data structure design would be greatly appreciated!

```
public Hashtable<Object,Object> searchRollupTree(Hashtable<Object,Object> tree, String searchTerm){
     Hashtable<Object,Object> returningTable = tree;
     for(Object item: tree.keySet()){
         if(tree.keyset().contains(searchTerm)){
            returningTable = (Hashtable<Object, Object>) tree.get(searchTerm)
            return returningTable;
         }else{
              searchRollupTree((Hashtable) tree.get(item.toString()),searchTerm);
         }
     }
     Hashtable<Object, Object> voidReturningTable = new Hashtable<Object,Object>();
     voidReturningTable.put("NotFound","Null");
     return voidReturningTable;
     }

}
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem? with your code? It looks correct to me.

Comment: To improve efficiency, you could avoid creating a new "voidReturningTable" every time that you end up in a leaf, and return an object defined on your class (or null) instead

Comment: you could also look at some iterative search algorithms, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem come from your else if you find the hahstable at a depth further of 1, you will not return it.

```
public Hashtable<Object,Object> searchRollupTree(Hashtable<Object,Object> tree, String searchTerm){
     Hashtable<Object,Object> returningTable = tree;
     for(Object item: tree.keySet()){
         if(tree.keyset().contains(searchTerm)){
            returningTable = (Hashtable<Object, Object>) tree.get(searchTerm)
            return returningTable;
         }else{
            returningTable = searchRollupTree((Hashtable) 
              tree.get(item.toString()),searchTerm);
           //assuming NotFound is only a key if no table was found
           if(!returningTable.containsKey("NotFound"){    
             return returningTable;
           }
        }
    }
    Hashtable<Object, Object> voidReturningTable = new Hashtable<Object,Object>();
    voidReturningTable.put("NotFound","Null");
    return voidReturningTable;
}
```

P.S: You should check before calling searchRollupTree that's the element is indeed a HashTable before going throught it. (probably going to throw an execption if you don't).

EDIT: putted the return of voidTable outside of the loop since it only passed by the first element of each HashTable

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't seem to do the trick,  replaced my else statement with yours and added the statement, "returningtable.put("NotFound","Null");" and returned returningtable at the bottom instead of voidReturningTable..

I also tried just removing, !returningTable.containsKey("NotFound" out completely, but I'm still returning the wrong table i believe.

Comment: Yes, excuse me i had miss read your code an assumed you returned a voidTable after the loop, currently you only check the first element of each table you go throught.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think i got it after further considerations from @molf 's and @Michele Da Ros 's suggestions. I was really close. All I needed to do was return null when a value is not found and check to see if returningTable  is a hashtable when the value is returned.  Here is my final answer:

```
public Hashtable<Object,Object> searchRollupTree(Hashtable<Object,Object> tree, String searchTerm){
 Hashtable<Object,Object> returningTable = tree;
 for(Object item: tree.keySet()){
     if(tree.keyset().contains(searchTerm)){
        returningTable = (Hashtable<Object, Object>) tree.get(searchTerm)
        return returningTable;
     }else{
          searchRollupTree((Hashtable) tree.get(item.toString()),searchTerm);
          If(returningTable  instance of Hashtable){
              return returningTable;
          }
     }
 }
 return null;
 }
```